# How should SOA - based application architecture look like?

Tags: oracle, web-applications, architecture, soa

If I want to create application based on webservices that OSB would serve - what should be it's architecture?

ie. if I use Oracle SOA Suite, I create WebServices that will do my bussiness (talk to DB etc.), put them on OSB (Oracle Service BUS). If I'd want to create app (webapp) that will utilize those services, how shoud I create project? 
Would it be war with gui and its logic, separate jar for EJB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're looking for how to structure a web application that calls OSB web services.  This is no different than a web application calling any other web service.

You shouldn't need EJBs for that, rather you can invoke the web services directly from java via JAX-WS or another mechanism.

For guidelines on structuring an application .ear, see
http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html
or your application server's documentation.